# How to click few buttons with same xpath, class

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a problem clicking every button on the LinkedIn page. In some profiles which contain a lot of information about job experience, schools, license we have to expand this information by click on 'Show more button".

[Sample profile 1](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jakub-bialoskorski/?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAABp5UJ8BDpi5ZwNGebljqDlYx7OXIKgxH80)

[Sample profile 2](https://www.linkedin.com/in/marcinstyrna/?originalSubdomain=pl)

I try many things like searching for elements by Xpath and then looping them to click every button on the page but it didn't work - because every button class is the same as other elements that we can find using selenium. I figure it that first "show more" button is always for experiane section and that code make job to click it:

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(
            self.driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li-icon[@class='pv-profile"
                                                                        "-section__toggle-detail-icon']"))))
```

Then we have the education section, license, and certification section - this makes me trouble. Temporary solution is to click at element that contain string:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Pokaż więcej')]").click()
```

OR

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Pokaż 1 uczelnię więcej')]").click()
```

Sooner than later I know that code has a lot of limitations. Does anyone have a better idea of how to solve this problem?

## Solution

```
containers = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li-icon[@class='pv-profile-section__toggle-detail-icon']")
    for button in containers:
        self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', button)
```

Comment: maybe use `find_elements_by_xpath` with char `s` in word `elements` to find all objects and get them as a list - and then you can use `for`-loop to click one by one.

Comment: your links need to login so we may not see pages (PL: twoje linki wymagają zalogowania więc może ich nie zobaczyć)

Comment: Yes, I am logged during this operation so this is not a problem.

Comment: did you try to use `find_elements_by_xpath` with char `s` in word `elements`? `find_element_by_xpath` without `s` in word `element` can gives only first element on page (if you run it with `driver`) or you have to first get all `containers` with offers and later use `for`-loop (`for single_container in all_containers`) with `single_container.find_element_by_xpath` to get first element in every `single_container`

Comment: Yup, I've tried this.
`buttons = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='pv-profile-section__card-action-bar pv-skills-section__additional-skills artdeco-container-card-action-bar artdeco-button artdeco-button--tertiary artdeco-button--3 artdeco-button--fluid artdeco-button--muted']")))
        for but in buttons:
            button = WebDriverWait(container, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li-icon[@class='pv-profile-section__toggle-detail-icon']")))
            button.click()`

It did not work

Comment: you could put it in question with erorr message. But don't use `Wait` inside `for`-loop - us edirectly `for but in buttons: but.click()` because inside `Wait` you use `element_to_be_clickable` which search only first element. And/or you should use `but` instead of `container`

Comment: Thank you, I put the solution above.

Comment: you can put solution as answer and mark your answer as accepted, and few minutes later you can upvote your answer. This way you can get some points in `reputation score`. And solution will be more visible for other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested page with own code and it seems you can get all buttons with

```
items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="profile-detail"]//button')

for item in items:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", item)
```

But there can be other problem. Page uses `"lazy loading"` and it may need to use JavaScript code which scrolls down to load all component.

---

Here is my full code with some ideas in comments.

I tried also select buttons in sections but not all methods work.
But maybe it will be useful for other ideas.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
import time

USERNAME = 'XXXXX'
PASSWORD = 'YYYYY'

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/jakub-bialoskorski/?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAABp5UJ8BDpi5ZwNGebljqDlYx7OXIKgxH80'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# -------------------------------------

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

#wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

cookies = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@action-type="ACCEPT"]')
cookies.click()
time.sleep(1)

link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//p[@class="authwall-join-form__subtitle"]/button')
link.click()
time.sleep(1)

login_form = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="authwall-sign-in-form"]')
time.sleep(1)

username = login_form.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="session_key"]')
username.send_keys(USERNAME)
password = login_form.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="session_password"]')
password.send_keys(PASSWORD)
time.sleep(1)

#button = login_form.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]')
button = login_form.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Zaloguj się")]')
button.click()
time.sleep(5)

# -------------------------------------

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/jakub-bialoskorski/?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAABp5UJ8BDpi5ZwNGebljqDlYx7OXIKgxH80'

#from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

# -----------

print('... scrolling for lazy loading ...')
     
last_height = 0
while True:
    
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + window.innerHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)    

    new_height = driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height      

# -----------

def click_items(items):
    for item in items:
        print('text:', item.text)

        #print(item.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

        #print('... scrolling ...')
        #ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).perform()
       
        print('... scrolling ...')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", item)
        
        #print('... clicking ...')
        #item.click()
        #time.sleep(1)

        print('... clicking ...')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", item)
        time.sleep(1)
        
        print('----')
   
print('\n>>> Pokaż <<<\n')

#items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Pokaż")]')
#click_items(items)

print('\n>>> Doświadczenie - Pokaż więcej <<<\n')

#section = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//section[@id="experience-section"]')
#items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "zobacz wi")]')
items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class, "inline-show-more-text__button")]')
click_items(items)

print('\n>>> Umiejętności i potwierdzenia - Pokaż więcej  <<<\n')

#section = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//section[@id="experience-section"]')
items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-control-name="skill_details"]')
click_items(items)

print('\n>>> Wyświetl <<<\n')

items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Wyświetl")]')
click_items(items)

print('\n>>> Rekomendacje <<<\n')

items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-controls="recommendation-list"]')
click_items(items)

print('\n>>> Osiągnięcia <<<\n')

print('--- projects ---')
items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-controls="projects-expandable-content"]')
click_items(items)

print('--- languages ---')
items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-controls="languages-expandable-content"]')
click_items(items)

# --- all buttons ---
#items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="profile-detail"]//button')
#click_items(items)
```